# How to rotate video that comes from android device with same quality by using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to rotate video that comes from android device that always display in landscape form; so how we convert into portrait form with a same quality.
I am using these code but unable to find exact code.

```
$ ffmpeg -i $inputfile -vf "transpose=1" $outputfile
$ ffmpeg -i $inputfile -acodec copy -vcodec copy -vf transpose=1 $outputfile
```

Not worked for me...

Comment: The possible duplicate link contains an answer that includes additional methods to rotate, so it isn't just about 180°. Rotation requires using filters ([except for MJPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#mjpeg2jpeg) + `jpegtran`), and filters require you to re-encode, so you may have to accept some quality loss (but you may not notice), or use a lossless encoder, but lossless usually makes outputs with giant file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate video using -vf "transpose=1".

Comment: When i am using this command -[-vf "transpose=1"]. i am getting an error - "timebase 1/90000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535"

Comment: @GauravBansal Without your actual command and the console output we can only provide guesses, not answers.